# No module named 'conda' in Pycharm Terminal

Tags: anaconda, conda, miniconda

When I start a Terminal in Pycharm I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jon/anaconda3/bin/conda", line 12, in <module>
    from conda.cli import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'conda'
```

I don't have conda in /home/jon/anaconda3/bin/conda
My conda is in /home/jon/miniconda3/bin, which I recently installed. So I believe there is a clash somewhere.

This is my PATH:

```
/home/jon/miniconda3/bin:/home/jon/miniconda3/condabin:/home/jon/anaconda3/bin:/usr/local/cuda/bin:/usr/local/cuda/lib64:/home/jon/bin:/home/jon/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/home/jon/bin': not a valid identifier
```

How can I resolve the clash?

Comment: Then why do you have `/home/jon/anaconda3/bin` in your PATH? Do you have an old anaconda installation lying around there?

Comment: @FlyingTeller Yes. It is old. I am not using it for the current project. But would like to leave it there for old stuff.

Comment: You should not need multiple anaconda/miniconda installations side by side. What is the benefit? Have one installation with different environments for different projects. Then you can activate them as needed. Your current setup is just a recipe for trouble (as you see in your error)